# Can't add rectangles into rectangle list

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

When I run this code, it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
here

```
clickableArea.Add(temp);
```

here is the entire class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace ScreenManager
{
class Menu
{
    public List<string> MenuItems;
    private List<Vector2> Position;
    private int iterator;
    public string InfoText { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Rectangle> clickableArea;


    public int Iterator
    {
        get
        {
            return iterator;
        }
        set
        {
            iterator = value;
            if (iterator > MenuItems.Count - 1) iterator = MenuItems.Count - 1;
            if (iterator < 0) iterator = 0;
        }
    }

    public Menu()
    {
        Title = "Title";
        MenuItems = new List<string>();
        MenuItems.Add("New Game");
        MenuItems.Add("Options");
        MenuItems.Add("Exit Game");
        Iterator = 0;
        InfoText = string.Empty;
    }



    public int GetNumberOfOptions()
    {
        return MenuItems.Count;
    }

    public string GetItem(int index)
    {
        return MenuItems[index];
    }

    public void DrawMenu(SpriteBatch batch, int screenWidth, SpriteFont arial)
    {
        batch.Begin();

        Vector2 FontOrigin = arial.MeasureString(Title) / 2;

        batch.DrawString(arial, Title, new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - arial.MeasureString(Title).X / 2, 20), Color.LightGreen, 0, FontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);

        int yPos = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < GetNumberOfOptions(); i++)
        {
            Rectangle temp;

            Color colour = Color.White;
            if (i == Iterator)
            {
                colour = Color.Gray;
            }



            batch.DrawString(arial, GetItem(i), new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - arial.MeasureString(GetItem(i)).X / 2, yPos), colour);

            int reclengthX = (int)arial.MeasureString(MenuItems[i]).X;
            int reclengthY = (int)arial.MeasureString(MenuItems[i]).Y;

            int recposX = (int)(screenWidth / 2 - arial.MeasureString(MenuItems[i]).X / 2);

            temp = new Rectangle(reclengthX, reclengthY, recposX, yPos);

            clickableArea.Add(temp);

            yPos += 50;
        }
        batch.End();
    }

    public void DrawEndScreen(SpriteBatch batch, int screenWidth, SpriteFont arial)
    {
        batch.DrawString(arial, InfoText, new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - arial.MeasureString(InfoText).X / 2, 300), Color.White);
        string prompt = "Press Enter to Continue";
        batch.DrawString(arial, prompt, new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - arial.MeasureString(prompt).X / 2, 400), Color.White);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. As problems like this usually are.

Comment: HI slefi, you should take a look into using the debugger in your IDE.  Stepping through code and inspecting values will help you identify the problem.  GDSE considers it off topic to ask us to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

`clickableArea = new List<Rectangle>();`

...needs to come first. Your list is not yet instantiated, so you cannot add anything to it. All you have there at the moment is an empty reference.

Comment: clickableArea = new List<Rectangle>(); to be exact. The constructor is a good place to instantiate the list.

Comment: oh wow, i cannot belive i did not see that, thanks

Comment: @dadooGames Thanks corrected. Java on one screen, C# on the other.

Comment: @slefi Remember to hit the checkmark beside my answer, if this solved your problem.